# Build Failed in react native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I was working with react native in my windows 10 for months. after upgrading to windows 11 and installing previous tools , I am not able to run my react native project . I installed android studio , SDK, JDK, node and other tools like before. but I got this error after running `npx react-native run-android` command:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\React Native Projects\myapp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: C:\Users\Username\Documents\React Native Projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\codegen\generator\SchemaJsonParser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\React Native Projects\myapp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\Username\Documents\React Native Projects\myapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Username\Documents\React Native Projects\myapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Username\Documents\React Native Projects\myapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Username\Documents\React Native Projects\myapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

This question was asked many times before, but I did not get an answer from them . I tried `gradlew clean` but I get same error (Build Failed). for some developers `chmod +x gradlew` worked. but it is for Linux and Mac. I am using windows . is there any replacement command for windows or other way to fix this problem ?
thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio Settings and follow this path. Open the dropdown for Gradle JDK and select 11 from the dropdown.

[image]